# Enumerate does not work with 2d arrays yet range(len()) does?

Tags: python

I heard somewhere that we should all use enumerate to iterate through arrays but

```py
for i in enumerate(array):
    for j in enumerate(array[i]):
        print(board[i][j])
```

doesn't work, yet when using range(len())

```py
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(len(array[i)):
        print(board[i][j])
```

it works as intended

Comment: Enumerate basically turns every element of the list or array into a tuple of two elements where one is the counter and one is the actually "old" element. Check the documentation on this, and post the error code you get when trying to run this?

Comment: Simply replacing `range(len(...))` with `enumerate(...)` would not work. You should check the documentation before using some function you don't know. It should be `for i, row in enumerate(array): for j, element in enumerate(row): print(board[i][j])`. Anyway you don't even need `enumerate` here as you don't need the elements. Just use the `range(len())` loop...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Of coruse, if the mixed use of `array` and `board` is a typo (highly likely), they don't need `range` or `enumerate`, and should just be doing `for row in board: for cell in row: print(cell)` and avoiding indexing entirely.

Answer (score 2):

use it like this:

```
for idxI, arrayI in enumerate(array):
    for idxJ, arrayJ in enumerate(arrayI):
        print(board[idxI][idxJ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Like I wrote enumerate adds an extra counter to each element. Effectively turning you list of elements into a list of tuples.

Example

```
array = ['a', 'b','c','d']
print(list(enumerate(array)))
```

gives you this:

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

So in your case what you want to do it simply add the extra element when iterating over it

```
for i, item1 in enumerate(array):
    for j,item2 in enumerate(array[i]):
        print(board[i][j])
```

Issue was in your case is

```
for i in enumerate(array):
```

this `i` is not an integer but a tuple `('1','a')` in my case. And you cant access a list element with an index value of a tuple.

Comment: If it's actually `array` in all cases, you'd just `print(item2)` instead of `print(array[i][j])`, and similarly, use `for j, item2 in enumerate(item1):`, since `enumerate` is giving you the values for free. As the OP has it, they don't even need `enumerate`, since they only use the index for reading values, and direct iteration avoids even that much waste.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am unable to see your point.

Comment: The point is that, in the code you provided, you don't need to use the indices at all, and using them (instead of the values you got for free through iteration) is pointless (and relatively inefficient). `enumerate` could be dropped entirely. The OP is using `enumerate` for cargo cult programming; demonstrating a better cargo cult isn't a big improvement.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You might want to read OPs question again. I was merely providing an explanation what was going on with his code and why one option works but the other doesnt.

Comment: My comment was because you *also* changed the use of `board` to `array`, matching the thing being looped over. When it was `array` being `enumerate`d, and `board` being indexed, `enumerate` makes some sense; when you change it so it's uniformly `array`, it stops making sense.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Are you really arguing naming convention right now? While ignoring the logic of the error?

Comment: It's not naming convention. The OP used two names, you used one (doesn't matter what the names are). It changes the "right" answer when you do that. To be clear, nothing wrong with also addressing the correct use of `enumerate` (I did not downvote or anything), but when someone says "I know nothing except I should always use `enumerate` instead of `range`", fixing their use of `enumerate` without addressing the misconception (`enumerate` is only needed when you *need* the index, and direct iteration is preferable) is omitting something crucial to the OP's understanding.

Comment: To be clear, I think this the best answer so far, it's just missing one thing that would make it complete.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Edited the question. And if board and array arent the same dimension... this gives index out of bounds error, so Its very poor practice to index over one list while accessing another.

Answer (score 1):

When one uses `for i in enumerate(array):` it returns a collection of tuples. When working with enumerate, the (index, obj) is returned while range based loops just go through the range specified.

```py
>>> arr = [1,2,3]
>>> enumerate(arr)
<enumerate object at 0x105413140>
>>> list(enumerate(arr))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> for i in list(enumerate(arr)):
...     print(i)
... 
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
>>>
```

One has to access the first element of the tuple to get the index in order to further index.

```py
>>> board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> for idx1,lst in enumerate(board):
...     for idx2,lst_ele in enumerate(lst): # could use enumerate(board[i])
...             print(lst_ele,end=" ")
... 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>>
```

Sometimes you do not need both the index and the element so I do not think its always better to use enumerate. That being said, there are plenty of situations where its easier to use enumerate so you can grab the element faster without having to write element = array[idx].

See [range() vs enumerate()](https://realpython.com/lessons/range-vs-enumerate/)

> "Both are valid. The first solution [range-based] looks more similar to the problem description, while the second solution [enum-based] has a *slight* optimization where you don’t mutate the list potentially three times per iteration." - *James Uejio*